# Animate a div layer popping up

Tags: javascript, css, animated

I'd like to create this layering effect with a div popping up and floating above the original.

https://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/22691/screenshots/1644434/gif_animation.gif

Is there an animation framework that would work best for this? Is it best to do it with javascript? or maybe css?

Comment: Did you mean CSS 3d transform?

Comment: I'm not sure what the best approach is. It could be CSS transforms like this http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-cube.php or some javascript animation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bounce.js turned out to be exactly what I was looking for.